# Why does "rails s" command say its not installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I installed Rails, then verified that it was installed:

```
rfhosting:~ macuser$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.12

rfhosting:~ macuser$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

Then I went to my app and tried to run it:

```
rfhosting:constructify-on-rails_ryan_072613 macuser$ rails s

Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I did this step, and it said a number of gems were installed, with the same exact result again.

I had one error while installing, however I have no idea what it's about. I don't have reps so I can't post a pic but this is what the error said:

```
error copying file from packed archive/Users/macuser/Downloads/RailsInstaller-1.0.4-0sx-10.7.app/contents/MacOS/installbuilder to / user/local/rvm/help/rvmrc
```

Additional info:

```
rfhosting:~ macuser$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p371]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3-p125
[ruby-]1.9.3-p194
[ruby-]1.9.3-p286
[ruby-]1.9.3-p327
[ruby-]1.9.3-p362
[ruby-]1.9.3-p374
[ruby-]1.9.3-p385
[ruby-]1.9.3-[p392]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc1
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc2
ruby-head

# GoRuby
goruby

# Topaz
topaz

# TheCodeShop - MRI experimental patches
tcs

# jamesgolick - All around gangster
jamesgolick

# Minimalistic ruby implementation - ISO 30170:2012
mruby[-head]

# JRuby
jruby-1.2.0
jruby-1.3.1
jruby-1.4.0
jruby-1.6.5.1
jruby-1.6.6
jruby-1.6.7.2
jruby-1.6.8
jruby[-1.7.3]
jruby-head

# Rubinius
rbx-1.0.1
rbx-1.1.1
rbx-1.2.3
rbx-1.2.4
rbx[-head]
rbx-2.0.testing
rbx-2.0.0-rc1

# Ruby Enterprise Edition
ree-1.8.6
ree[-1.8.7][-2012.02]

# Kiji
kiji

# MagLev
maglev[-head]
maglev-1.0.0

# Mac OS X Snow Leopard Or Newer
macruby-0.10
macruby-0.11
macruby[-0.12]
macruby-nightly
macruby-head

# Opal
opal

# IronRuby
ironruby[-1.1.3]
ironruby-head
```

Comment: What is the output of the command  `rvm list known` If it is empty try `rvm install 1.9.3` followed by `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`

Comment: close an re-open a terminal, it will reload the aliases (short-cuts commands like `rails server`, etc)

Comment: How did you install ruby and rails?

Comment: Mr Yoshiji, Yes I tried that, same results.

Comment: Don't append the output of RVM and other commands as comments. Append them to your answer and format them properly so they're more easily readable.

Comment: Vimsha, I used railsinstaller.org.

Comment: Tin Man, OOps sorry ok will do

Answer (score 0):

I went through the installation a few weeks ago with my Mac using RVM.

Let's see if this can work for you too.

---

Step 1: Install RVM

Type this in the terminal:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

This will do some stuff and print a long message which you can ignore.

---

Step 2: Configure your shell - Configure your shell
type `rvm | head -1`

Expected result: `rvm is a function`

Type    `rvm -v`
Approximate expected result:

```
rvm 1.x.x (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com), Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

---

Step 3: Install Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM

```
rvm install 1.9.3

rvm use 1.9.3

rvm --default use 1.9.3

ruby -v
```

Approximate expected result:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to refer the official website installing guide. I suggest you remove it and reinstall according to the official guide. Try:

```
$curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=1.9.3
```

After it is installed, run:

```
$source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

To load RVM's environment refer to: https://rvm.io/ and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html